# SQL server 2008 replication without reinitialize

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two databases in different servers - `center_db` on `siglv01\sql2008` and `center_db` on `sig\sql2008`.

Can I restart replication without needing to reinitialize it? The connection dropped more than 3 days ago and is now too slow: so I want to start replication without a reinitialize.

Comment: That depends. Why is it currently stopped? *How* is it currently stopped (i.e. is the distribution or log reader agent not running? is one of those agents throwing errors?)?

Comment: connection doped more than 3 days and connection now is too slow
so i want to start replication without reinitialize

Answer (score 0):

Based on the brief conversation above, I don't think you can do this without a re-init. Specifically, the distribution database only keeps so many commands before it starts trimming. The default is 72 hours. If the last command delivered to all of your subscribers is older than that, the distribution database doesn't have what it needs to play forward all of the activity that has happened since then.

Your only hope would be if the distribution agent is still running (it knows when the above situation happens and will give you an error saying as much). If so, try to figure out why delivery is slow (troubleshoot this like any other "slow application"; replication isn't magic) and see if it can get caught up that way. Depending on how many commands are remain undelivered, it may be faster to just re-init.